# Is there any disadvantage to Windows Fast Startup (Hybrid shutdown/boot)?

Tags: windows-10, hybrid-boot

I just received my refurbished laptop (better hardware) from Dell and upgraded to Windows 10. However, I noticed that the shutdown and boot up times were longer than my old laptop, which had Windows 8.1 with lower hardware specs. I came to understand that the Fast Startup feature was not enabled. After turning it on, the faster boot and shutdown times have returned again.

So I get that this feature is an improvement over the hibernate mode, but is there any disadvantage to using the feature? I'm not trying to dual boot or attempt any fancy techniques with my computer. I just wonder if there's any downside to using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast Startup enables your computers fast boot times by only logging off the current user and protecting part of system related files and drivers to the hibernation file. There is no real disadvantage of using this feature, however should you experience any issue, a simple restart is in essence the same as shutting down the computer in non-Fast Startup mode.

Answer (score 2):

A disadvantage is dual booting other operating systems. A Windows that was shutdown this ways can't start other operating systems like Linux. [Linux detects the hibernated Windows and blocks any mount actions to the Windows partition to prevent data loss](https://askubuntu.com/a/145904).

Comment: Thank you for the technical information. However, I chose the other answer because I already addressed in my question that I do not plan to attempt anything complicated like dual booting and that I was merely looking for an immediate disadvantage.